# unable to create cda project, no available cda document in workspace eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cda, mdht

I am a beginner on Model Driven Health Tools (MDHT) in Eclipse. I want to create new CDA model but it gives this message: "Unable to create CDA project, No Available CDA Documents in Workspace"

How to solve it?

[image: error message]

Answer (score 0):

Currently you need to have the core CDA project in your workspace for the wizard to use;  using the following psf file you should be able to import the projects.

You can use the one found here https://sourceforge.net/projects/oht-modeling/files/Project%20Set%20Files/

Going forward you can use the following site to communicate with the project team: [Eclipse Model Driven Health Tools](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/modeling.mdht).

Comment: I did a 'File -> Import -> Team -> Team Project Set' and selected the 'mdhtcda.psf'. Everything appeared to be ok but I still get the same message ''unable to create cda project, no available cda document in workspace". Is there any additional step? I do not use Eclipse very often.

Answer (score 0):

Download the setup file at https://sourceforge.net/projects/oht-modeling/files/Project%20Set%20Files/

Open Eclipse -> import -> team -> team project set
select your .psf file and click finish

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Project_Set_File